# Using postman to add pins on the board on pinterest

Tags: postman, pinterest

How can we make an http request in postman to add pin to the pinterest board. I have my board name and board Id. I have to attach image to this board. Please guide me through this!

Comment: Here's the Pinterest API for developers. From a very fast viewing, it's very simple API... https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/pins/

Comment: What have you tried so far?